# How to stop flexbox item growing

Tags: css, grid, flexbox

I want to stop the bottom item growing to the height. I want the bottom right flexbox item to only be the height of its contents (how it would be with `display: inline-block;`).

The grid and grid items have:

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-wrap: wrap
```

Please see attached image:

[image]

Comment: Please include full code (HTML and CSS) to allow us to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should create another container around your bottom element.

```
<div class="container"> /* This container will be grown by Flex*/
    <div class="grey-box"> /* This container will remain the same height as its children */
        /* content */
    </div>
</div>
```

And you must apply the following properties to your `.container` div:

```
.container {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

With the proper pre-fixes ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was facing a very different issue: unable to center the items when `flex-direcion: column;` was applied, so I added `align-items: center;` below it and it worked.